# failing to create image in azure ml workspace

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am able to create image and run azure ml service in one env but when I am moving to another env its not able to create image and failing with this error -

Message: Received bad response from Model Management Service:
Response Code: 500
{"code":"InternalServerError","statusCode":500,"message":"An internal server error occurred. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact support.","correlation":{"RequestId":"8667981d-ef71-4e7c-a735-c43ef07b51b8"}}'

these logs are not helpful to find issue

Comment: What do you mean by image? Can you include the code you use to create an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message said, this issue is an internal issue, please raise a support ticket to assign a support engineer to investigate it.